# Artificial TCP reordering in WireShark

Tags: wireshark, tcp

In the process of testing a software product, the question is to test the scope of allowable share TCP reordering, which can sustain the program
Does Wireshark or other similar software Product Sheet possibility of artificial introduction TCP reordering the existing pcap-file
That is, the challenge is to introduce distortion into an existing pсap-file and specify, for example, that it is necessary to rearrange forcedly 20% or 30% of the packets in the general case N packets
Unfortunately, a search in Google gave no adequate results
Thanks in advance

=================

Expert survey showed that there is a special tool to re-sort TCP traffic in pcap-file called **TcpReplay**
([TcpReplay site](http://tcpreplay.appneta.com/))
Surprising that it is impossible to find in Google on any keyword about PCAP, TCP reordering, and so on, but **TcpReplay** does exactly what you need

=================

In fact, to solve this problem by means of network tools and failed, apparently because this problem is rare in network testing software
The result is a small utility in the language Perl, which performs predetermined resorting for TCP-packets at random; there is only one variable parameter **$rand_factor**, showing the percentage of the random permuted packages
In fact, the utility re-sorts Ethernet-frames, that is actually sorting touch-and UDP-packets, and service traffic, but it has no negative impact on the practice, for the ultimate goal - a random permutation for TCP-packets - properly executed
Use of health:
[Artificial TCP reordering tool in Perl](http://pastebin.com/w4sLBaL5)

Comment: maybe one search in google would have given adequate results? (double negations are not not bad) But I think that a google search is not to be considered as research anyways.

Comment: It seems like you would need a tool that gets a pcap file with a tcp flow and scrambles the order of the packets and produces a different pcap file. Is that what you are after ?

Comment: @cnicutar Absolutely, requires just such a tool !
Use - load testing network software, which is built in mechanisms to restore order of TCP-packets in flow
If you know of a console utility or plug-in for WireShark, please indicate such

Comment: I don't know of any such tool but it would be pretty feasible to build: many major languages have libraries to handle pcap files.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: No

Wireshark is a tool to dissect captures; Wireshark itself has no capability to re-arrange frames.

The Wireshark suite does have some tools to randomize certain bytes of a capture files and to do things like removing duplicate frames from a capture file, but no capability to re-arrange the order of TCP PDUs.

Answer (score 0):

I've used NEWT on Windows (google it) in the past. It doesn't permit modification of existing pcap files but there's nothing to stop you using NEWT to stress the network and then wireshark to capture the results of your test for analysis.

Comment: Thank you! Proposed you Network Emulator Toolkit for Vindovs really interesting solution, and I think it will be useful for further research 
Expert survey showed that there is a special tool to re-sort TCP traffic in pcap-file called TcpReplay
Surprising that it is impossible to find in Google on any keyword about PCAP, TCP reordering, and so on, but TcpReplay does exactly what you need